# Optimisation Trigger, Code repetition

Tags: trigger

I currently have a trigger working properly but I have to much code repetition
I am pretty sure that the code can be optimized with a map to avoid repeating IF Statements, but not sure how to go about it.
Could someone help?

Thanks

```
trigger ContactRolesDefaultValue on Contact (before insert, before update) {

//Optimise code with Map
Map<Id, Contact> contactMap = new Map<Id, Contact>();

if(Trigger.isInsert) {
    for(Contact c : Trigger.New) {
        if(c.Cooperative_groups__c != null && c.Cooperative_groups__c.Contains('RoleDefaultValue1')) {
            c.RoleDefaultValue1__c = 'Membre';
        }
        
        if(c.Cooperative_groups__c != null && c.Cooperative_groups__c.Contains('RoleDefaultValue2')) {
            c.RoleDefaultValue2__c = 'Membre';
        }
        
        if(c.Cooperative_groups__c != null && c.Cooperative_groups__c.Contains('RoleDefaultValue3')) {
            c.RoleDefaultValue3__c = 'Membre';
        }
        
        if(c.Cooperative_groups__c != null && c.Cooperative_groups__c.Contains('RoleDefaultValue4')) {
            c.RoleDefaultValue4__c = 'Membre';
        }
    }
   
}

List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT LastName, Cooperative_groups__c FROM Contact WHERE Cooperative_groups__c != null AND Id IN:Trigger.New];
System.debug('contactList ' +contactList);

if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
    if(contactList.size() > 0) {
        
        for(Contact c :Trigger.New) {
            if(Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Cooperative_groups__c.Contains('RoleDefaultValue1') && c.Cooperative_groups__c == null
                && c.Cooperative_groups__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Cooperative_groups__c) {
                    
                c.RoleDefaultValue1__c = '';
            }
            
            if(Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Cooperative_groups__c.Contains('RoleDefaultValue2') && c.Cooperative_groups__c == null
                && c.Cooperative_groups__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Cooperative_groups__c) {
                    
                c.RoleDefaultValue2__c = '';
            }
            
            if(Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Cooperative_groups__c.Contains('RoleDefaultValue3') && c.Cooperative_groups__c == null
                && c.Cooperative_groups__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Cooperative_groups__c) {
                    
                c.RoleDefaultValue3__c = '';
            }
            
            if(Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Cooperative_groups__c.Contains('RoleDefaultValue4') && c.Cooperative_groups__c == null
                && c.Cooperative_groups__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Cooperative_groups__c) {
                    
                c.RoleDefaultValue4__c = '';
            }
            
        }
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```java
trigger ContactRolesDefaultValue on Contact(before insert, before update) {
    Map<String, sObjectField> rolesToCheck = new Map<String, sObjectField>{
        'RoleDefaultValue1' => Contact.RoleDefaultValue1__c,
        'RoleDefaultValue2' => Contact.RoleDefaultValue2__c,
        'RoleDefaultValue3' => Contact.RoleDefaultValue3__c,
        'RoleDefaultValue4' => Contact.RoleDefaultValue4__c
    };

    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        for (Contact contact : Trigger.New) {
            for (String roleToCheck : rolesToCheck.keySet()) {
                if (contact.Cooperative_groups__c != null && contact.Cooperative_groups__c.contains(roleToCheck)) {
                    contact.put(rolesToCheck.get(roleToCheck), 'Membre');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (Contact contact : Trigger.New) {
            for (String roleToCheck : rolesToCheck.keySet()) {
                Contact oldContact = Trigger.oldMap.get(contact.Id);

                if (
                    oldContact.Cooperative_groups__c != null &&
                    oldContact.Cooperative_groups__c.contains(roleToCheck) &&
                    oldContact.Cooperative_groups__c != contact?.Cooperative_groups__c
                ) {
                    contact.put(rolesToCheck.get(roleToCheck), '');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I see a few issues with this code:

- You should not store code directly in the trigger. Create handler class and move logic there.
- I removed the query. You have `Cooperative_groups__c` in Trigger.New.